# java I/O disk performance comparaison between windows and mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, io

While testing performance for my application written in java I tested the disk I/O speed with a simple RandomAccessFile. I run the test on two platform : a macbookpro, and a windows 10 with SSD drive given at a speed of 400-500Mb/s. Both disk performance where almost the same and where mesured with Black magic disk speed test.

I was very surprised when I saw a gap between windows and mac with the same java kind code running on two platform. **The WINDOWS is 2.5 SLOWER than MAC**.
I cannot explain such a gap. Has anyone a clue about such a difference, or do you have the same king of gap between those platform.
Thanks for your help

Note :

Of course, antivirus was disable on windows.

You can find a sample of code for test here :http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.fr/2011/12/java-sequential-io-performance.html

You can also test with JDiskMark, I had the same factor between the two platforms

Test where made with jdk 1.8.0_92

Comment: This question is for System adminstrator. From experience, accessing, reading/writing from Windows FAT partition is much slower than UNIX in comparison.

Comment: No, I think this is a java question, since I realized a benchmark coded in C (I guess) and the files IO where at the same rate 400Mb/s on both partition

Comment: OK I found, it was linked to windows energy mode. Now SSD are so fast that you can quickly become CPU bound when you write data.

Comment: Windows are generally slower and that is why most servers are running on Linux/Unix. Yes, disk speed is the bottleneck factor and the FAT architecture also plays the part.